# crefrange with different reference types in Cleveref

Tags: cleveref

I am using the `Cleveref` package and in my document defined multiple new cross-reference types that all refer to figures, i.e.,

```
\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\Crefname{fig_a}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\creflabelformat{fig_a}{#2{\color{NavyBlue}#1a)}#3}
\Crefname{fig_b}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\creflabelformat{fig_b}{#2{\color{NavyBlue}#1b)}#3}
\Crefname{fig_c}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\creflabelformat{fig_c}{#2{\color{NavyBlue}#1c)}#3}
```

The reason for this is that I have figures that contain parts **a)**, **b)**, etc., but not as subfigures but as mere labels in the precompiled figure.
So, in order to reference individual parts of such a figure, I thought I could add multiple labels to the same figure, i.e.,

```
\begin{figure}
  ...
  \caption{Figure with parts a) and b) and c)}
  \label{figure}
  \label[fig_a]{figure:a}
  \label[fig_b]{figure:b}
  \label[fig_c]{figure:c}
\end{figure}
```

Now I would like to be able to write

```
\Cref{figure:a,figure:b}
\Cref{figure:a,,figure:c}
```

and get a reference as if all those references were of type `figure`, so something like *Fig. **3.2a)** and **3.2b)*** and *Fig. **3.2a)** to **3.2c)***. However, as all those references are of different types, what I get is *Fig. **3.2a)** and Fig. **3.2b)*** and *Fig. **3.2a)** to Fig. **3.2b)***.

How can I get rid of the second *Fig.* in a range of references?
I tried to solve this with `\crefalias{fig_a}{figure}` but this did not solve the problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide more details about the nature of `fig_a`, `fig_b`, and `fig_c`. You wrote, "...all those references are of different types." What are these types? Are they subfigures? If that's not the case, what are they?

Comment: I edited the post to include my use-case. By "types" I mean `fig_a`, etc., so what is defined by `\Crefname{<type>}{...}{...}`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, some of your `figure` environments contain images with embedded parts (panels?) and associated hard-coded "labels" (a), (b), etc. Put differently, each of these `figure` environments contains a single `\includegraphics` statement. Is this interpretation correct? If it is, why not just create your cross-reference call-outs by writing, say, "`as shown in panels a) and c) of \cref{fig:fancy}, …`"?

Comment: Incidentally, if your Latex document features multiple `\label` directives for a given `figure` counter, Latex should be issuing pointed warning messages about labels getting "lost".

Comment: That's correct. This is what I am currently doing. I was simply wondering whether I could include a), b), c) in the reference, i.e., have the entire text "3.2a)" linked to the figure.

Comment: I suppose you could use the `\hyperlink`/`\hypertarget` machinery of the `hyperref` package to create multiple links to a given object. However, unless you think your readers may have a really hard time locating panels a), b), and c) within a given figure (in which case you *really* must improve the figure's readability!), you're not performing a useful service by providing hyperlinks that all point to the same object. The best solution, in my view, is to reconstruct the figures from scratch, so that each panel is associated with its own `subfigure` environment and counter.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by

```
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref} 
\Crefname{figure}{fig.}{Fig.}
\Crefname{fig_a}{fig.}{Fig.}
\creflabelformat{fig_a}{#2{\color{NavyBlue}#1a)}#3}
\Crefname{fig_b}{fig.}{Fig.}
\creflabelformat{fig_b}{#2{\color{NavyBlue}#1b)}#3}
\Crefname{fig_c}{fig.}{Fig.}
\creflabelformat{fig_c}{#2{\color{NavyBlue}#1c)}#3}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete, minimal example that highlights how this answers the question? Perhaps also include an image of the output for your example. Can you do that?